# Ошибка при подключении сокета к серверу: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, сокет, python-3.x

Собственно, ошибка: TypeError:

> a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Ошибка в строке " sock.send('Hello, World") "

Ошибка нашлась в приложении клиента, вот собственно код клиента:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))
sock.send('hello, world!')

data = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close()

print(data)
```

Вот код сервера:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

print('connected:', addr)

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    conn.send(data.upper())

conn.close()
```

Я этот пример вообще списал, т.к только-только (буквально пару минут назад) начал изучение сокетов, а тут такое.

Comment: а sock.send(bytearray('hello world!')) тоже не работает?

Comment: Нет, выдаёт ошибку: string argument without an encoding

Comment: ну осталось только кодировку указать :)  sock.send(bytearray('hello world!', "ascii"))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Метод `socket.send` ожидает последовательность байтов, а не строку. Чтобы преобразовать строку в последовательность байтов, можно воспользоваться методом `str.encode`:

```
sock.send("hello, world!".encode())
```

Аналогично, если вы хотите получить не последовательность байтов, а строку, то можно воспользоваться методом `str.decode`:

```
data = sock.recv(1024).decode()
```

По умолчанию в качестве кодировки будет использован UTF-8.

Comment: @Flaffen: нужно заметить, что код в вопросе работает без ошибок на Питоне 2, где `str` -- это последовательность байт. На Питоне 3, `str` -- это Юникодная строка (используется для текста). `.encode()`, `.decode()` используют `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, которая ascii на Питоне 2 и utf-8 на Питоне 3 по умолчанию.